# Class App\Http\Controllers\PostConstroller does not exist

Tags: laravel, class, laravel-5.8

Hello I try to create post with Laravel, but I have this error :

> Class App\Http\Controllers\PostConstroller does not exist

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'ProfileController@show')->name('profile.show');
Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostConstroller@create')->name('posts.create');
Route::post('/posts', 'PostConstroller@store')->name('posts.store');
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

and I can do for leave this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey you didn't notice you have spelling mistake in your import it should be `PostController` not `PostConstroller`

Change this

```
App\Http\Controllers\PostConstroller
```

to

```
App\Http\Controllers\PostController
```

and yes same issue is with your routes:

```
Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostConstroller@create')->name('posts.create');
Route::post('/posts', 'PostConstroller@store')->name('posts.store');
```

Change your routes to:

```
Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostController@create')->name('posts.create'); 
Route::post('/posts', 'PostController@store')->name('posts.store');
```

Thanks