# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PATCH

Tags: php, laravel, post, patch

Please I can't find where is the problem!

blade

```
<form action="/profile/{{$user->id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                @csrf
                @method('patch')
```

route

```
Route::patch('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesControler@update')->name('profile.update');
```

Error:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
>   PATCH.

edit 1- web.php

```php
Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome'); }); 
Auth::routes(); 
Route::get('/p/create','postsController@create'); 
Route::get('/p/{posts}','postsController@show'); 
Route::post('/p','postsController@store'); 
Route::get('/profile/{user}/edit', 'ProfilesControler@edit')->name('Profile.edit'); 
Route::get('/Profile/{user}', 'ProfilesControler@index')->name('Profile.show');
Route::post('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesControler@update')->name('profile.update')
```

Comment: be sure that you are submitting that form, and not another one that wrap this one

Comment: Hi Alberto, I only one form on my edit.blade.php, I have another form on creat.blade.php, but it's using another path,   It is amkin me crazy, i lost one dat tryin to fix it! hope you can help me

Comment: will you share whole `web.php` file here!

Comment: be sure to be loading this view and not another one... also check the source file in the browser to check what laravel has echo in the pagine with the @method directove

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<form action="/profile/{{$user->id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                @method('PATCH')
                @csrf

</form>
```

one more tip always use `route method` for routes as you have named route in your `web.php` so it will be easy to maintain and debug

```
<form action="{{route('profile.update',['user' => $user->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                @method('PATCH')
                @csrf
</form>
```

Read more about [method spoofing here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Hope it helps..

Thanks.

**Note:** if still problem persist try clearing your routes cache `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: I changed but the problem persist, it's making me crazy this error!

Comment: can you post your entire web..php file?

Comment: here it is:

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

route::get('/p/create','postsController@create');
route::get('/p/{posts}','postsController@show');
route::post('/p','postsController@store');
Route::get('/profile/{user}/edit', 'ProfilesControler@edit')->name('Profile.edit');
Route::get('/Profile/{user}', 'ProfilesControler@index')->name('Profile.show');


Route::post('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesControler@update')->name('profile.update')

Comment: @MouradMohammedBenosman change this `Route::post('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesControler@update')->name('profile.update')`
 to `Route::patch('/profile/{user}/update', 'ProfilesControler@update')->name('profile.update')`

Comment: When I remove the line  return redirect("/profile/1");   from:  public function update(User $user)
    {

        $data=request()->validate([

            'title'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required',
            'Url'=>'url',
            'image'=>'',


        ]);

        $user->profile->update($data);

       return redirect("/profile/1");
    }
}                   it works , can't understand why!?

Answer (score 0):

Change `<form action="/profile/{{$user->id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">`

To : `<form action="/profile/{{$user->id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="GET">`

Try again

**NOTE:** You cant upload images with GET,

EDIT: Give your route a name and then use it

like : `Route::post('/update', 'ProfilesControler@update');` or you can switch patch to post or to get

or : `Route::patch('/update', 'ProfilesControler@update')->name('update');`

```
Route::patch('/update', 'ProfilesControler@update')->name('update');
```

Comment: same error Dilek! The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PATCH.

Comment: I used get, and it works, but i red that it's better to work with patch or put when I want to update a table right?

Comment: @MouradMohammedBenosman I updated answer try to name your route as I show in answer

Comment: I changed all the web.php : The PATCH method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: See your own question edited by @SalmanZafar you needed to change patch to  post method in my question. see more here https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1843

Comment: @MouradMohammedBenosman See this one nice complete example set your routes like that : Here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/the-get-method-is-not-supported-for-this-route-supported-methods-post with `method="post"`

Comment: @SalmanZafar sorry,  one you asked for the entire web.php I was trying post, for this reason you find post rather than patch,

Comment: I'll see your link,

Comment: Can you try this `Route::post('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesControler@profile.update')->name('profile.update');` And this :`Route::patch('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesControler@profile.update')->name('profile.update');`

Comment: the class profile.update does not exist, i have update class: Method App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesControler::profile.update does not exist,

Comment: to the point i irrived, i can give you acees to my pc with team viewer if you want, i can't solve it!

Comment: Sorry I have no ideas left @MouradMohammedBenosman exept showing you this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019062/class-app-http-controllers-postconstroller-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0):

Before Answering your question.Let read some facts, To perform `resource` methods, you must follow some best practices.

**Uri** must follow this pattern **`/controllerName/methodName/{unique_identifier}`**

For `@index`,`@store`

```
Route::get('/profile/','ProfileController@index');
Route::post('/profile/','ProfileController@store');
```

*Above two route are identical, but their methods are different.*

For `@show`

```
Route::get('/profile/{user_id}','ProfileController@show');
```

For `@create`, `@edit`

```
Route::get('/profile/create','ProfileController@create');
Route::get('/profile/edit/{user_id}','ProfileController@edit');
```

For `@update`,`@destroy`

```
Route::put('/profile/update/{user_id}','ProfileController@update');
Route::delete('/profile/destroy/{user_id}','ProfileController@destroy');
```

Or you can use

```
Route::post('/profile/update/{user_id}','ProfileController@update');
Route::post('/profile/destroy/{user_id}','ProfileController@destroy');
```

For update request,Your `method` should be `PUT`; so

```
<form method="POST">
  @csrf
  @method('PUT')
  <!---whatever your code -->
</form>
```

or

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/', 'method' => 'PUT')) }}
    .... wathever code here
{{ Form::close() }}
```

> Note: Since HTML forms only support **POST** and **GET**, **PUT** and **DELETE**
>   methods will be spoofed by automatically adding a _method hidden field
>   to your form.

**In your case,** `method` was not set as it's route accept `PATCH` method, so please check your `@method('PATCH')` directive echoed associative `input element` in your `form` as expected as follows

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
```

> You must change ***ProfilesControler*** to **ProfileController**, as it was
>   wrong spelled

Answer (score -1):

Gys, I'm sure because I'm not sending the correct data, it's not workin as it must, here is my update function: public function

update(User $user) {

```
$data=request()->validate([

    'title'=>'required',
    'description'=>'required',
    'Url'=>'url',


]);


$user->profile->update($data);
return redirect("/profile/{$user->id}");
```

}
}