# update with patch method not working with laravel localization

Tags: php, laravel, routes, patch

I'm using Laravel 8 and working with Localization trying to update with patch route but it's showing error.
"The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PATCH."

My route is => `

```
Route::patch('/item/update/{item}', [SaleController::class, 'itemUpdate'])->name('item_update');
```

`

And the url generated is => `http://project.test/en/sale/item/update/1/`

What should I do now?

I'm trying to update with **PATCH** method with localization, but it's not working.

Comment: what method do you have set for your form?

Answer (score 0):

There are already answer for same problem
[The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59599911/the-get-method-is-not-supported-for-this-route-supported-methods-patch).
So please check your blade.php, something may be wrong there.

Comment: Kindly flag responses as duplicate rather than posting a solution using other solutions

Answer (score -1):

That error isn't related to laravel localization. When creating a request you need to define the http method too.
Just putting an url in browser make a GET request.

In html form you can determine the method in method attribute but only POST and GET are available. To define other method you can add a hidden input named _method:

```
<form>
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
</form>
```

Comment: I'm already using @method('patch') in form.