# Laravel update data with PATCH method

Tags: laravel

I want to update my data with Laravel so I used the PATCH method but I have an error :

Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for route checkPermissions. Supported methods: PATCH.

I used PATCH method like this :

My view :

```
    <form action="/checkPermissions" method="PATCH">
    @method('PATCH')
    @csrf

      //My fields are here

    </form>
```

My route :

```
Route::patch('/checkPermissions', [MyController::class, 'check']);
```

(I already check this Question [The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59599911/the-get-method-is-not-supported-for-this-route-supported-methods-patch), but there is no answers that solve the problem)

If you need to see more code or files just ask me.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: `method="POST"` instead of `method="PATCH"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form actions are only supported to get and post actions. Change the form action to post and you are already defined patch within the @method directive.

Comment: Thanks ! I don't really understand the logic... We have to set the method to POST to be able to execute a PATCH...

Comment: you cannot use PUT/PATCH - there's just no such methods supported by forms in browsers - it's only GET and POST. So how does Laravel make it work with @method('patch'). under the hood laravel constructs a hidden field with name _method and then checks it upon form submittion, routing it to the correct Controller method. Hope this clears out the confusion.

Comment: @Elias fyi: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#form-method-spoofing